# How to derive $|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle+|-\rangle)$?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, superposition

When learning measurement basis, my teacher told us $|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|+\rangle+|-\rangle)$ and said that we can derive it ourselves. Along this, he also mentioned  $|+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$.

I understand that when we visualize those vectors on a bloch sphere, $|0\rangle$ lies in between $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, and if we normalize the coefficient, we would get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. However, I'm confused how we know that the phase is + ($|+\rangle+|-\rangle$) instead of -? Is this just a definition for $|0\rangle$ or is it backed by a deeper reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via use of substitution, or via the expansion into vectors and comparison. However, for this and other expansions, I find the use of the identity operator, which can be diagonalised in all bases, is the most informative:

$$|0\rangle=I|0\rangle=(|+\rangle\langle+|+|-\rangle\langle-|)|0\rangle$$

$$=\langle+|0\rangle|+\rangle+\langle-|0\rangle|-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|+\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-\rangle$$

Comment: This is an interesting approach! Nice

Answer (score 3):

A way to see it is by writing the column representation of each state you mentioned:

$$
|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \; |1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \; |+\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \; |-\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

This way, it is easy to see why the phase of $|-\rangle$ in the state $|0\rangle$ needs to be positive ($+1$) and negative ($-1$) in the representation of $|1\rangle$.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done entirely in Dirac notation by substituting the definitions

$$
|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle) \\
|-\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)
$$

into $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle)$. We get

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|+\rangle + |-\rangle) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle) + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)\right)\\
&=\frac12|0\rangle + \frac12|1\rangle + \frac12|0\rangle - \frac12|1\rangle \\
&= |0\rangle.
\end{align}
$$